# how i can set value in <g:set var="x"> using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

I want to set value in grails  tag variable "x" using javascript or jquery

```
<g:set var="x" value="${}" ></g:set>

<script>
var y=10;
</script>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Can you please try to explain fully what you're trying to achieve? 
My best guess is that you want to update X (a groovy variable) from Javascript.
GSPs are processed when the associated render call is hit, while Javascript executes in the users browser, making what you wish impossible.

Comment: If what you want to achieve is something like what @JacobPersi states, then yes it might be imposible. You should explain what is the end result you are expecting. Depending on that wie might offer some advice on a workaround or a better solution.

Comment: I want to set value in variable 'x' using javascript or jquery.
Initially, the value of x=0 and on load, I want to set x=10 or any value in 'x'. It is possible to set value in grails g:set tag. I am new in grails programming.

Answer (score 0):

create a script file named as variable_tag.js and include it into your page that contains follwoing code:

```html
<g:set var="x" value="1000"></g:set>
<g:set var="y" value="x * 2"></g:set>
<g:set var="str" value="'ExampleText' + y" />

<!-- variable_tag.js --!>
<script>
   var setTags = document.getElementsByTagName("g:set");
    for(var i=0;i<setTags.length;i++){
      var name  = setTags[i].getAttribute("var");
      var value = setTags[i].getAttribute("value");
      window[name] =eval(value); 
    }

</script>

<script>
  console.log('x',x);
  console.log('y',y);
  console.log('str',str);
</script>
```

Comment: In Grails <g:set> is a custom tag to set variables used during the render process... they are not included in the output HTML. This is not an answer.